# How can I set the low power mode to "Only On Battery" programmatically?

Tags: macos, applescript, battery, power-management, ventura

How can I set the low power mode to "Only On Battery" programmatically?

[image]

Using `sudo pmset -a lowpowermode 0` sets it to "Always."

Comment: What does man give for the arguments of pmset ?

Comment: What does pmset show when you set it to "Only on Battery" using the GUI?

Comment: @benwiggy Unfortunately, it only uses `0` and `1`, which correspond to always off and always on.

Comment: @SolarMike I can't find anything relevant in the manpage.

Comment: So did you just make up that command or copy it from somewhere? If you copied it - did they give an explanation? And other arguments?

Comment: Is there no other value set for low power mode?

Comment: The man pages read: `The -a, -b, -c, -u flags determine whether the settings apply to battery ( -b ), charger (wall power) ( -c ), UPS ( -u ) or all ( -a ).`  So why are you using the -a (all) flag, instead of -b (battery)?

Comment: @Redarm Thanks, I missed that in the manpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -a, -b, -c, -u flags determine whether the settings apply to battery ( -b ), charger (wall power) ( -c ), UPS ( -u ) or all ( -a ). So:

```shell
function battery-low-power-mode-enable {
    sudo pmset -b lowpowermode 1
    # enables lowpowermode only when on battery
}

function battery-low-power-mode-disable {
    sudo pmset -a lowpowermode 0
    # disables lowpowermode for ALL power sources
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Things are a bit different since "high power mode" has been added in newer versions of macOS.  You can use "pmset -b powermode X" to set the power mode on battery power ("-c" instead of "-b" for when plugged in), where "X" is one of 0 (automatic), 1 (low power), or 2 (high power).